# Vertex is less influenced

Tags: modeling

[image]

I made a face.
The teeth move strangely.
When I rotate it, the other vertex works properly, but the center vertex doesn't move normally.
I feel like it's trying to maintain its current position.
I didn't give it a shape key.
I gave weight to the bone. Will it affect the vertex?
The problem is that the center vertex is less affected by the move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i unchecked topology mirror. and solve